# Error when i load data from a text file in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am totally new to Linux, python, and tensorflow.
I am having a problem to get a data from a separate text file.
Python codings are as below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

xy=np.loadtxt('train.txt',unpack=True, dtype='float32')

x_data=xy[0:-1]
y_data=xy[-1];

print 'x',x_data
print 'y',y_data
```

and error messages are as below.

```
root@bu-R470-R420:/home/bu# source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
tensorflow)root@bu-R470-R420:/home/bu# python -m tensorflow.linearLoad
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/root/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/linearLoad.py", line 5, in <module>
    xy=np.loadtxt('train.txt',unpack=True, dtype='float32')
  File "/root/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 803, in loadtxt
    fh = iter(open(fname, 'U'))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'train.txt'
(tensorflow)root@bu-R470-R420:/home/bu#
```

Since i have been using Windows OS, Coding in  Linux is a quite nightmare.
Please help me out.

Comment: Most likely you aren't working with the correct directory.  First just try to open and read the file as plain text. Focus on getting the right path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IOError` exception you are receiving means the file `train.txt` doesn't exist in the relative path.

The error message clearly shows it:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'train.txt'
```

Double check the file `train.txt` is present in the folder from which you are running your script, `/home/bu` in your case.

Comment: Sure. please tell me how to accept your answer. It is a first time for me to visit this site. I have pressed Up Arrow already, Is there anything more to do?